# How should I be handling MySQL connections if I am running queries as frequent as this?

Tags: c#, mysql

Please read the relative information below as it is specific to my question.

We have a lot of tasks that need to be programmatically completed for our platform. We currently have small C# applications we call workers who process these tasks and work together. We currently have 3 deployed.

These workers all read from a database with concurrency locks implemented, this is how they get each task from a database table called `queued_platform_tasks`.

So here is what each worker usually does for each task

```
Opens a new database connection
Runs a query to fetch the next task in queue
Closes the database connection
Processes the task (usually 3-4 seconds)
Opens a new database connection
Runs a query to mark it as completed
Closes the database connection
```

The average time to complete a task is 6 seconds, and never more than 10 seconds.

If the average is correct, that means it has to open a connection, run a query to fetch next task, close the connection, open it again, mark the last task as complete and close said connection 600 times an hour (per worker). With all workers that's 3,600 times an hour.

Should I keep the connection running for the duration of the worker (24 hours a day, unless downtime), or should I keep opening a new connection when a query is ready to run?

The workers could be running for days, weeks even months. A 3rd option would be to refresh the connection every X queries or X minutes.

**How does my worker application database code look?**

It's fairly simple and consists of only two classes.

DatabaseProvider:

```
public class DatabaseProvider : IDatabaseProvider
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DatabaseProvider(string databaseName, string password, uint port, string host, string username)
    {
        _connectionString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            Database = databaseName,
            Password = password,
            Port = port,
            Server = host,
            UserID = username,
            SslMode = MySqlSslMode.None,
            DefaultCommandTimeout = 30,
            CharacterSet = "utf8mb4",
            AllowUserVariables = true,
        }.ToString();
    }

    public DatabaseConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString);
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        
        return new DatabaseConnection(connection, command);
    }
}
```

DatabaseConnection:

```
public class DatabaseConnection : IDisposable
{
    private readonly MySqlConnection _connection;
    private readonly MySqlCommand _command;

    public DatabaseConnection(MySqlConnection connection, MySqlCommand command)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _command = command;

        _connection.Open();
    }

    public void SetQuery(string commandText)
    {
        _command.Parameters.Clear();
        _command.CommandText = commandText;
    }

    public void ExecuteQuery()
    {
        _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public DataTable ExecuteTable()
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        using var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(_command);
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);

        return dataTable;
    }

    public DataRow ExecuteRow()
    {
        DataRow dataRow = null;

        var dataSet = new DataSet();

        using (var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(_command))
        {
            adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        }

        if (dataSet.Tables.Count > 0 && dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            dataRow = dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0];
        }

        return dataRow;
    }

    public void AddParameter(string name, object value)
    {
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue(name, value);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            _connection.Close();
        }

        _connection.Dispose();
        _command.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var dbConnection = _databaseProvider.GetConnection())
{
    dbConnection.SetQuery("SELECT 1+1;");
    dbConnection.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: You gain nothing by using those classes, they replicate what ADO.NET already does, with more code and none of the abstraction benefits. If you use ADO.NET's abstract classes and providers you could use any database provider without changing your code. You don't need a DbDataAdapter to load a DataTable either, just `DataTable.Load(DbDataReader)` will work. Besides, most developers don't use DataTable any more, they use either full ORMs like EF Core or micro-ORMs like Dapper

Comment: If you wanted to reduce boilerplate you could use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just fine as you are. All this is managed by connection pooling: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-pooling.html

> Connection pooling works by keeping the native connection to the server live when the client disposes of a MySqlConnection. Subsequently, if a new MySqlConnection object is opened, it is created from the connection pool, rather than creating a new native connection. This improves performance.

You don't need the intermediate class. Create and dispose the my sql connection before and after running your queries.

Comment: Quite the opposite. This mimics ADO.NET's own classes, without the advantages. Yes, connection pooling still works but other things have problems

Comment: My point is about disposing the connection each time. Did I miss something in the question?

Comment: Just noticed that he is disposing a custom class.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras thank you for your reply, sure connection pooling ensures that I am using the same connection, but should I be keeping that connection open for 2 queries rather than one? Or is this micro optimizing? Each worker is single-threaded, so only one database connection is required to power it for days and days.

Comment: Check the code, especially `ExecuteTable`. Weakly typed parameter values are going to cause trouble, allowing the wrong parameter values to pass.

Comment: @AAA why are you using such code? What are you trying to gain? This isn't about connection pooling, a simple `using` fixes that. Why add an abstraction like this?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras I use this code because I dislike abstraction, its a personal preference thing. Unless I am doing something wrong in my custom classe(s) I don't see how it is relevant to my question.

Comment: It's no optimising at all AAA. Don't keep them alive a second more than needed. Return them to the pool as soon as possible. They are not really closed, so you'll be fine. The longer you keep them open, the more likely you'll need to really create a new connection.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what else has problems? Could you elaborate so I can attempt to fix them if true.

Comment: Panagiotis makes a very valid point though. You are discarding type safety by creating an abstraction like this.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are you trying to say it is too tightly coupled to MySQL driver?

Comment: @AAA there are too many problems. The use of datatables, bundling connections and commands, using `object` parameters. Again, what problem are you trying to solve? Why not use ADO.NET directly? Or use `Dapper` and have it bind parameters to *strongly* typed values *and* handle connection lifetime in a single line?

Comment: @AAA with Dapper. you would write `con.Query<MyRecord>("select * from sometable where Created>@date", new {date=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5)});` and get back a list of strongly-typed objects. The connection would be opened and closed as needed by Dapper itself

Comment: I wouldn't use Dapper due to it being an abstraction and potentially being just as slow as EF core, I use my custom code as it is very easy to work with and can be changed to support other drivers if required. I don't think there are any issues related to my question with my custom classes, just general bad practice?

Comment: @AAA no and no and no. It's not slow, definitely faster than EF Core and you're building your own abstraction after all, one that breaks ADO.NET's abstractions *and* can easily suffer from conversion errors due to `AddWithvalue`. Using a DataTable and a DataAdapter are slowing things down too

Comment: I will address any issues mentioned here with my implementation, although I will not be switching, partially because it is not my decision. If you could mention any additional issues I should have a look at, who knows maybe you can even persuade me to become a dapper fan if enough issues are mentioned ;). I have marked this answer as correct as it explains the solution to my primary question. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding the opening and closing of connections for each query, there is no problem with your code. Regarding the bundling and the abstraction, I'll have to agree with Panagiotis. The cost of creating/destroying connections is negligible.

Comment: @AAA Go for Dapper, it's fast as hell, sometimes is even faster than using directly the ADO classes, it is very optimized. I've been using it for years and it is the best option.

Comment: @Gusman could it outperform my current implementation in speed? I am debating it!

Comment: @AAA Indeed! Using dapper to map strongly typed classes outperforms by far the usage of datarows and objects, Dapper uses IL to map values to classes, you will not find anything faster than that, even if you do it manually for specific values Dapper is faster.

Comment: I will mention it to my co-worker and see what he thinks, thank you for the recommendation, I am now team Dapper if this is true.